# time complexities of java loops

Tags: java, algorithm

How to find time complexities for the following loops.

1)

```
int I, j, k, n, mini, tmp;
for(i = 0; i< k; i++){
    mini = i;
    for(j =i +1; j < n; j++)
        if (a[j] < a[mini])
            mini = j;
        tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[mini];
        a[mini] = tmp;
    }
    return a[k-1];
}
```

2)

```
void SelectionSort(int A[], int n) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n - 1) {
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < n) {
            if (A[j] < A[i])
                swap(A[j], A[i])
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code and edit your post and what is the question?

Comment: I think the first loop has a missin `{`. Indentation is necessary for anyone to read the code

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Comment: What do you think complexity of these loops is and why do you think so?

Comment: One option would be to ask a question on SO and wait till the response magically pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Both are `O(n^2)` <sup>1,2</sup>

In both, the outer loop runs from 0 to n (exclusive), and for each iteration - the inner loop runs from i+1 to n (exclusive).

If we sum the running time of the inner loops we get:

```
n- (0+1)  + n- (1+1) + .... + n-(n-1 + 1) = 
= n-1 + n-2 + .... + 0 =
0 + 1 + ... + n-1 = (*)
n(n-1)/2
```

which is in `O(n^2)`

The equation (*) comes from [sum of aritmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

As a side note - both are sorting algorithms, the first is min sort and the second is as the function name says, selection sort.

---

(1) technically the first is `O(k^2)`, but I assume it means the same here.

(2) Assuming the `return a[k-1];` should be AFTER closing the scope of the outer loop, and its placement is a mistake. If it is not a mistake - the outer loop runs only once, and complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: There is a `return` statement inside the outer for loop of the first snippet, so the time complexity is `O(n)` not `O(n²)`.

Comment: @fabian Thanks you , I missed the scoping. I believe it is a mistake, but I will add a clarification about it. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Please explain the time complexities for these two code snippets a little bit widely.